# Porting old CDT Debug Plugin to Eclipse NEON

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

Hy i would like to Port an old Eclipse plugin to work with current Eclipse version NEON 2.
Can be found here: https://github.com/pmlopes/minpsp-eclipse-plugin

My Problem it uses the Extention Point: **org.eclipse.cdt.mi.core.factories.CommandFactoryDescriptor**
and a lot of other stuff from org.eclipse.cdt.mi.*

As i understand this is used to create a gdb mi command interpreter.

**Is there a new alternative to this?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CDI - the CDT Debugger Interface - was removed in CDT 9.0 as it was no longer being supported for many years (i.e. no code contributions, it had numerous issues and presented usability issues.)

Of course there is a debugger interface in CDT still, it is called DSF - the Debugger Service Framework - and has been actively developed for more than a decade. It has been the default debugger interface in CDT for many years now too.

I have looked at your code briefly. Fortunately AFAICT you are only configuring GDB settings, that is relatively easy to port over to DSF, many of the settings are the same.

The first question to ask is are you actually using Legacy CDI or have you always been using DSF? If you have actually been using DSF then have a read through the [API modifications](https://wiki.eclipse.org/CDT/User/NewIn90#API_modifications) for CDT 9.0. I have recently updated them to help answer other people porting over code that looked similar to yours.

Please ask any additional questions as new SO questions and I will do my best to answer.

---

CommandFactoryDescriptor is a CDI concept, it does not apply to DSF where the wiring is done very differently.

Comment: Thanks for reply i'm currently reading through dsf. The Code wasn't written by me, i just like to get this to run and learn some thing about cdt. :)